# Want my loop to away and back

Tags: java, for-loop

What im trying to get :

```
Welk woord wil je Af/Opbouwen?
MARSEPEIN
MARSEPEIN
MARSEPEI
MARSEPE
MARSEP
MARSE
MARS
MAR
MA
M
MA
MAR
MARS
MARSE
MARSEP
MARSEPE
MARSEPEI
MARSEPEIN
```

What i got now :

```
welk woord wil je op en af?
marsepein
marsepein
marsepei
marsepe
marsep
marse
mars
mar
ma
m

m
ma
mar
mars
marse
marsep
marsepe
marsepei
marsepein
```

But the problem with my program is that there is space between the redirection. Is there another/better way i can do this?

my code:

```
System.out.println("welk woord wil je op en af?");
String woord = s.next();

for (int i = woord.length(); i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(woord.substring(0, i));


    if (i == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= woord.length(); j++) {
            System.out.println(woord.substring(0, j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 independent loops would be neater to read and reason than nesting these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop from length down to 1:

```
for (int i = woord.length(); i >= 1; i--) {
    System.out.println(woord.substring(0, i));
}
```

Then loop from 2 back up to length:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= woord.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(woord.substring(0, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("welk woord wil je op en af?");
String woord = s.next();

for (int i = woord.length(); i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(woord.substring(0, i));


    if (i == 1) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= woord.length(); j++) {
            System.out.println(woord.substring(0, j));
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the loop variable values essentially.
Making `i>0`
Checking `i==1`
and initialising `j=2`

Answer (score 0):

change the conditions in the for loops

```
for (int i = woord.length(); i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(woord.substring(0, i));

        if (i == ) {
            for (int j = 2; j <= woord.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println(woord.substring(0, j));
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need two loops.

Here is a possible solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2*woord.length() - 1; i++) {
        int endIndex = i < woord.length() ? woord.length() - i : i - woord.length() + 2;
        System.out.println(woord.substring(0, endIndex));            
    }
```

The loop always runs for `2 * length - 1` times. In first phase it moves left along the length of the string by doing `woord.length() - i` and once the first character is reached i.e. `i < woord.length()`, it moves towards right. As you don't want an empty string and the first character printed twice the `+ 2` part of the code skips those sysouts.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a bit more difficult haha

Comment: Well, don't get intimidated by the `ternary operator` it just does the below:
`if(i < woord.length()) {
woord.length() - i;
} else {
i - woord.length() + 2;
}`